# Android Network Service Discovery APIs: Not Available In Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: android

I'd like to use Android's [NSD (Network Service Discovery) APIs](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html#discover), but I want my app to support all versions of Android 4.0.0.

However, the API for NSD showed up in 4.1, Jelly Bean, and isn't present in 4.0, Ice Cream Sandwich!

I tried the latest support library (requiring a minimum of Android version 13) but that didn't have the NSD APIs either.

I'm thinking I shouldn't have a problem simply taking Android source 4.1 or later, copying all the classes I can find for NSD, and giving it a try in my own custom type of support library.

I find it really weird this API is not in the support library? This is standard network transport stuff.